# a mathematic model for multi-factor rating system

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling

I have to design a rating system for a eCommerce website. The rating with be like 1 - 5 or 1 - 100. There're multiple factors need to be considered to give the rating, like user feedback, customer support quality, delivery rate etc, and they all have different weight on how they affect the rating. Is there a mathematical model for this case?

Comment: How do you evaluate what is a good vs. bad rating? Eg. is the rating supposed to be a forecast of something?

Comment: Not sure what the objective is, but you may want to think about principal component analysis (PCA) which is basically about dimensionality reduction. If you're trying to forecast something with your factors, you may want to look at linear regression.

Comment: This sounds like a problem for machine learning.

Comment: @MatthewGunn it doesnt forcast anything, just show to users as a overall sevice quality.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the factors are the $3$ you have given,
their respective weightages (decimal fractions) are $w_1, w_2, w_3$
and the ratings given to them (on whatever scale you have chosen) are $r_1,r_2,r_3,$

then the simplest model is:
Overall score $= w_1r_1 + w_2r_2 + w_3r_3, $

$$\text{In general, for $k$ factors,} \sum_{k=1}^k w_kr_k$$

*EXAMPLE*
Suppose the weightages are $0.4, 0.3, 0.3$
and the ratings $3, 2, 3$
then Overall rating = $(0.4*3) + (0.3*2) + (0.3*3) =
2.7$